# Struct labeling

Tags: c, struct, label

In C I would like to be able to label a specific location within a struct. For example:

```
struct test {
    char name[20];

    position:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Such that I could do:

```
struct test srs[2];
memcpy(&srs[1].position, &srs[0].position, sizeof(test) - offsetof(test, position));
```

To copy the position of srs[0] into srs[1].

I have tried declaring position as type without any bytes however this didn't work either:

```
struct test {
    char name[20];

    void position; //unsigned position: 0; doesn't work either
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

I am aware that I could embed the x and y within another struct called position:

```
struct test {
    char name[20];

    struct {
        int x;
        int y;
    } position;
};
```

Or just use the location of the x property:

```
struct test srs[2];
memcpy(&srs[1].x, &srs[0].x, sizeof(test) - offsetof(test, x));
```

However I was wondering if there was a way to do what I had initially proposed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct test {
    char name[20];

    char position[0];
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

0 length arrays are/were quite popular in network protocol code.

Comment: Just what I needed! You could even take it a step further with: typedef char struct_label[0];

Comment: +1, nice example, it should be added it is not C but a GNU extension.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using C11 an anonymous union with an anonymous structure :

```
struct test {
    char name[20];

    union {
        int position;
        struct {
            int x;
            int y;
        };
    };
};
```

The address of `position` is the address of the next structure members after `name` member.

I show it only for the sake of showing it as the natural solution is to just take the address of member `x` in the first structure declaration of your question.

Comment: This is a good solution however declaring position as an integer looks misleading.

Comment: @CHRIS it is declared as an `int` so it is the same type as `x` member and so it is made explicit than the addition of `position` does not increase the size of the `union`. OTOH the type is not important as we don't take the value of the member but its address.

Comment: Yes, but the value may still be used, as opposed to if it were a true label. I suppose const int would be more fitting but its purpose is still unclear at first glance if someone else were to maintain the code later on.